# submit form over ajax redirect to php file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to submit my form with ajax, so the user doesn't need to leave the current page; but the submit always takes me to the submit.php ... What am I doing wrong? I've tried different pieces of code I found on the internet, but it keeps going wrong...

Thx in advance!

script:

```
<script>
    var theForm = document.getElementById( 'theForm' );

    new stepsForm( theForm, {
        onSubmit : function( form ) {
            // hide form
            classie.addClass( theForm.querySelector( '.simform-inner' ), 'hide' );

            theForm.submit(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                $this = $(this);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: $this.attr('action'),
                    data: $this.serialize(),
                    success : function(){
                        var messageEl = theForm.querySelector( '.final-message' );
                        messageEl.innerHTML = 'Super! Je bent ingeschreven! We verwachten je 27 maart om 20u00 op de chiro!';
                        classie.addClass( messageEl, 'show' );
                    }
                });                  
            });

        }
    });
</script>
```

php

```
<?php

    $naam = $_POST['q1'];
    $email = $_POST['q2'];
    $afdeling = $_POST['q3'];
    $kleur = $_POST['q4'];
    $message = $_POST['q5'];

    $to  = 'myemail@email.be';
    $subject = 'Inschrijving OLA Activiteit';
    $body= "
        <br><hr><br>
        Naam: $naam <br><br>
        Email: $email <br><br>
        Afdeling: $afdeling <br><br>
        Kleur: $kleur<br><br>
        <br><br><br>
        bericht:<br> $message <br>
        <br>
        ";
    $headers = "From: $email\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";

    if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) { // this line checks that we have a valid email address
        mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers); //This method sends the mail.
    }
?>
```

UPDATE: I managed to fix this...

```
        <script>
        var theForm = document.getElementById( 'theForm' );

        new stepsForm( theForm, {
            onSubmit : function( form ) {
                // hide form
                classie.addClass( theForm.querySelector( '.simform-inner' ), 'hide' );

                $("#theForm").submit(function(){

                    $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: $(this).attr('action'),
                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                    success : function(){
                    }

                 });
                });

                var messageEl = theForm.querySelector( '.final-message' );
                messageEl.innerHTML = 'Super! Je bent ingeschreven! We zien je graag 27 maart om 20u00 aan de chirolokalen!';
                classie.addClass( messageEl, 'show' );
            }
        } );
    </script>
```

Comment: add return false after ajax call

Comment: The problem doesn't seem to be in this code. I think your submit button in the form does too much work. Just add a normal button, not a submit. You only need to be executed your JavaScript code. Maybe it helps if you show your form.

Comment: You should add `return false` at the end of `theForm.submit` function;

Comment: return fals is not working.. I'm using this kind of form http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/04/01/minimal-form-interface/

Comment: When you look at the source of the demo page, there is no method or action attribute on the form-element. You probably added those. http://tympanus.net/Development/MinimalForm/